# PyObject in QT Creator

Tags: c++, python-3.x, qt-creator

I currently doing a task that required calling python function from Qt Creator. I am able to include `<Python.h>` but I can't find PyObject or anything related to python when coding. Every time I try to use PyObject it always says:

```
use of undeclared identifier 'PyObject'
```

***test.py***

```
import math
def myabs(x):
return math.fabs(x)
```

***test.cpp***

```
#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#include <Python.h>
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
 PyObject* myModuleString = PyString_FromString((char*)"test");
 PyObject* myModule = PyImport_Import(myModuleString);
 PyObject* myFunction = PyObject_GetAttrString(myModule,(char*)"myabs");
 PyObject* args = PyTuple_Pack(1,PyFloat_FromDouble(2.0));
 PyObject* myResult = PyObject_CallObject(myFunction, args)
 double result = PyFloat_AsDouble(myResult);
}
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: show your .pro..